# Directionservice Route Waypoints Literal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating an angularjs directive with the google maps direction service. What I am doing is performing a getFunction in my controller and scopeing a watch variable. Once the scope variable changes, I update my directions with the calculateAndDisplayRoute function. I am trying to use the waypoints feature but keep getting boggled down on the same issue. Waypoints array is supposed to be specified as an array of objects containing the fields "location" and "stopover". I have a google.maps.Place object with the retrieved from geocoding in an array named wypoints. I currently have waypoints array of 8.

What I am having trouble with is that the waypoints don't accept a LatLng field in the location section which I am really confused about.

The following is my calculateandDisplayRoute function:

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, waypoints) {
                var waypts = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < waypoints.length; i++) {
                        waypts.push({
                            location: waypoints[i].geometry.location,
                            stopover: true
                        });
                    }

                directionsService.route({
                    origin: waypts[0].location,
                    destination: waypts[waypts.length - 1].location,
                    waypoints: waypts,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function (response, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                    } else {
                        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                    }
                });
            }
```

The error I keep getting is that I get Zero_results.

While I am at it, I also have another issue which if I remove all waypoints, I notice that the directionService.route sometimes gives me either the Zero_result, Gives me start and end of points at waypoint[0] and waypoint[8], or lastly sometimes gives me start and end points of waypoint[0] and waypoint[//some number between 0-8]. I am assuming this is because this is anasynchronous call? I don't think it should matter since the waypoints are being defined prior to the function even running.

Thanks for anyhelp!

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: @SabarishSenthilnathan I will work on one to get to you later today.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/obbL19ra/ This isn't a working sample because I'm not sure why the watch isn't working in this one, but it shows the basic concept of what I am doing.

Comment: Awesome, let me look at it.

Comment: Yea sry I know you asked for a working one but seems like I'm running into issues just creating the fiddle lol. Let me know if you need any clarification. If you think there's another way of doing this please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle showing the route for the points provided - http://jsfiddle.net/af6f7su0/140/

The reason why you get zero results is because directions for the region you provided is not available. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) says

> "ZERO_RESULTS" indicates that the geocode was successful but returned
>   no results. This may occur if the geocoder was passed a non-existent
>   address

I find the fiddle you provided has duplicate placeIds and that would cause the Direction Service API to return zero results. I removed one of the duplicate placeIds in the updated fiddle. Also, the location geometry of the placeIds provided is somehow showing up in the wrong place and I modified the fiddle to use `formatted_address` instead of `location.geometry`. Ensure that all points fall in a land area. Also, you have included all of the points as the `waypoints` property, but only the intermediate points (except the first and last one) should be a valid value for this property. Here's the updated `calculateAndDisplayRoute` function:

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, waypoints) {
     var waypts = [];
     var intermediatePoints = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < waypoints.length; i++) {
         waypts.push({
             location: waypoints[i].formatted_address,
             stopover: true
         });
     }

    intermediatePoints = waypts.slice(1, -1);

    directionsService.route({
        origin: waypts[0].location,
        destination: waypts[waypts.length - 1].location,
        waypoints: intermediatePoints,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
       directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
       window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if not.

Comment: Let me look through the code and I will get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that I've called `$scope.apply()` in the directive as we change the `$scope.map_address` model outside of the angular context

Comment: Thanks it looks great. One of the issues I have is that I noticed that in your example the listings/waypoints are always placed out of order when you refresh the page. Where A, B, and C are always changing, is there a way to modify that or specifically edit the waypoints?

Comment: I think the order of the waypoints are preserved, but the marker behaviour is erratic. You can control what marker goes to each waypoint. There is suppress marker option in the DirectionsDisplay  that removes the default AB markers. And when looping through the waypoints you can a add a custom marker to that. These examples would help - [change marker label](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels) and [custom direction marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex). Hope it helps.